# Nginx global conf for running php scripts

Tags: nginx, php, configuration, fastcgi

To configure Nginx to process a PHP app, one can create a **dedicated** conf file under `sites-available` and then create an according symlink under `sites-enabled`, but I don't want to use this method - I prefer one **global** conf for running php scripts, for all projects. Something that could be putted inside `nginx.conf`. I didn't find such a global conf anywhere.

Is there a Nginx global conf for running php scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. You just need to keep you project in a folder accoding to it's domain name ($host)
Check nginx variables:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  8192;
}


http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;



    server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/$host;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

    rewrite /files/$ /index.php last;

    if ($uri !~ wp-content/plugins) {
        rewrite /files/(.+)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        client_max_body_size 25M;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Your approach is interesting but it seems not to work, please read: https://serverfault.com/questions/894776/nginx-global-conf-breaks-nginx

Comment: I edited my answer. This config works. Tested with wordpress 4.9.2, nginx 1.12.1 and php-fpm 7.0