# Nginx global conf breaks Nginx (updated)

Tags: nginx, php, configuration, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've added the following global conf to the `http` block inside `nginx.conf`.

The purpose is to cover all php apps (WordPress apps and PHPmyadmin) in one block of conf, instead creating multiple conf files and their symlinks.

```
http {
    ..........................................
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www/$host;
        location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
        location ~ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    ..........................................
}
```

### My problem

This configuration breaks the system - as long as it's inside `nginx.conf`, the system breaks.

The full (updated) `nginx.conf` [can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36891d3786f98651d349836512c3dfef).

The only error in `nginx -t` is regarding this line `listen 80 default_server;` and it says:

> a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65

### My question

Why does my global code breaks Nginx?

Comment: In your case you should use only one 'listen 80'. grep -rl 'listen 80' /etc/nginx . And you should adjust your nginx config for your wordpress. examples is here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Place a `server` stanza after the general configuration and it will be more likely to work - the configuration is read from top to bottom so any settings in your virtual host configurations would overwrite the settings as shown there.

Also, you can test your configuration with `nginx -t` which is helpful in showing where errors are.

Answer (score 0):

```
  location {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
```

you don't have a `location_match` on that particular location block. Simply changing it to

```
            location ~ {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            }
```

makes your configuration file valid.

Explanation:

```
Location blocks generally take the following form:

location optional_modifier location_match {

    . . .

}
The location_match in the above defines what Nginx should check the request URI against. The existence or nonexistence of the modifier in the above example affects the way that the Nginx attempts to match the location block. The modifiers below will cause the associated location block to be interpreted as follows:

(none): If no modifiers are present, the location is interpreted as a prefix match. This means that the location given will be matched against the beginning of the request URI to determine a match.
```

> =: If an equal sign is used, this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given.
>
> ~: If a tilde modifier is present, this location will be interpreted
>   as a case-sensitive regular expression match.
>
> ~*: If a tilde and asterisk modifier is used, the location block will
>   be interpreted as a case-insensitive regular expression match.
>
> ^~: If a carat and tilde modifier is present, and if this block is
>   selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression
>   matching will not take place.

Comment: Hi, I changed as you suggest but still have the same problem. Please see my update in the question. There seem to be another problem.

Comment: I'm using the `nginx.conf` you've provided in a link in your question. When updating the location block which errors out (line 15), the configuration file passes successfully syntax validation check:

`[root@server nginx]# nginx -t`
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: Hmm strange. Will you allow to post your full `nginx.conf` so I'll compare the two in a `diff tool`?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aJ6Q6d

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see for yourself:

```
# nginx -t -c /tmp/nginx_test.conf
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /tmp/nginx_test.conf:15
```

He doesn't like `location {`, I guess.